# How to get history of a web brower like google chrome in c++ ?

Tags: c++, browser, browser-history, wininet

I am working on a program in c++ and i need to get history of a web browser (default) or any like google chrome so what functions will help to get history ?
Is there any function in wininet?

Comment: Every browser does its own thing.. so, you have to implement a different solution for each browser you want to support. Sorry, no shortcuts available..

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome stores it's history in SQLite DB. So it's pretty easy to open and read it. History of visited sites stored in a file named **History**. Path to the default user history is different for the different versions of OS. On Windows XP:

> C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

On Windows Vista and later:

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Preferences

The hardest part here is to convert **visit time** to user-friendly format. This value stored in **visits.visit_time** as number of microseconds since Jan 1, 1601 UTC.

Comment: And the primary "take away" is that "there's no standard way to do this" - not even with the same browser on different operating systems.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Typically same browser on different OSs has the same history format, but different location, e.g. Chrome. Unfortunately, there is no "silver bullet" for browser history parsing, you need to support each format separately.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @JesperJuhl By the way, there is not too much popular engines to support. It's Chrome, Fire Fox and IE. Opera now uses Chromium, so it has the same history format as Chrome.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, you right

Answer (score 1):

Wininet is for networking so it wouldn't make sense for such a function to be there. I would export the history to an intermediary format (Firefox does it to HTML) and find a library to read that.